# iOS Mapkit - SetRegion error

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Could you point me what is wrong with this code?

```
-(void) showStoreRegion:(NSInteger)idx
{

    //StoreLocation* store = [self.listStore objectAtIndex:idx];

    //self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(store.latitude,store.longitude);

    self.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10.7500,106.6667);

    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta  = 0.001;
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.001;

    region.span = span;
    region.center = self.coordinate;


    [theMapView setRegion:region animated:TRUE];
    [theMapView regionThatFits:region];


    [self addAnns];

}
```

I got this message "terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid Region '
" when run this code/

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialised your region propertly. Try this

```
MKCoordinateSpan span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.001,0.001);
MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMake(self.coordinate, span)
```